# Does Databricks have a google cloud Big Query equivalent of --dry_run?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

Databricks uses DBU's as a costing unit whether based onto of AWS/Azure/GCP and I want to know if Databricks has a google cloud Big Query equivalent of --dry_run for estimating costs? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure databricks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/databricks/) calculates costs associated with DBU’s as shown in below table

[image]

[AWS calculates](https://databricks.com/product/aws-pricing/instance-types) it as shown in the table below

[image]

But Unfortunately, Databricks do not have a google cloud Big Query equivalent of `--dry_run` for estimating costs